# How to access to Django ORM DB in pytest?

Tags: python, django, orm, pytest

I am writing a smoke test for a POST request to API Django using pytest. With a Post request, I write the value to the DB and check that it appears. The data from POST request appears in the database, but the test fails due to the error below.

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from json_import.models import Sensor
import pytest

BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8000"
POST_URL = "/api/write_values"


@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestAPI:
    def test_smoke(self):
        body = {
            "timestamp": f"{datetime.now()}",
            "sensor_values": [
                {
                    "sensor_id": "sensor1",
                    "value": "1.1"
                }
            ]
        }
        response = requests.post(f'{BASE_URL}{POST_URL}', json=body)
        sensor1 = Sensor.objects.get(sensor_id='sensor1')
        sensor_value1 = sensor1.sensor_values.last()
        assert sensor_value1.sensor_value == 1.1
```

Received error

```
E           json_import.models.Sensor.DoesNotExist: Sensor matching query does not exist.

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:435: DoesNotExist
```

Migrations are done, py test.ini is created.

What could be the problem?
I was looking for a solution to the problem in the documentation and on the forum.

Answer (score 0):

Hi how are you? What is the response from your response api when you submit the post? The answer is 200? or 201? or something else?
It's created ?

Another thing, try changing BASE_URL to the resource name, you can do it with python manage.py show_urls but this is an extension https://pypi.org/project/django-showurls/

I say this because your url will not always be the one you have, and it can change depending on the environment you use (prod, qa, devel, etc) and the tests can fail.

Comment: Jonny, thanks for you advice, i will try it.
The answer for post response is 200.
BASE_URL is constant and it equal to "http://localhost:8000"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).